# How to add pixels to a current position of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to move an image from its current position to the right, so I need to add pixels to the left position that it has right now.

I have a `flex` container in which I have an `image` and a `div`. Both of them are centered on the container with `justify-content: center;` property.

The problem I have is that when I try to move the image that has position `absolute`, it goes back until its nearest parent that has position `relative` (its container) and start to add pixels there and it makes a strange visual effect.

**HTML** code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="moveImage()">Move image</button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" class="block">Left</div>
  <div id="center" class="block">
    <img id="image" src="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" alt="stackoverflow">
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="block">Right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS** code:

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

.block{
    flex: 1;
}

#left{
    background-color: red;
}

#center{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background-color: yellow;
    justify-content: center;
}

#right{
    background-color: orange;
}

#divCentered{
   width: 50%;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: brown;
}
```

**Javascript** code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var divParent = document.getElementById('center');
     var div = document.createElement("div");
     div.setAttribute("id", "divCentered");
     divParent.appendChild(div);
});

function moveImage(){
  $("#image").animate({
    left: "+=300px"
  }, 1000);  
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om6gt7z0/) in which you can see how the image goes back until its parent and start adding pixels there.

Is there a way to avoid that the image back some pixels to its parent and start add pixels in its current position?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of proves, I have got a workaround to get this.

I have to use [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) property to get the *container* and the *image* `left` property taking as reference the document.

Then, I have to set the `left` property of the image to 0 because it would be positioned when the `container` is positioned on the left (as the container is the `relative` parent of the `absolute` image).

After that, just substract both values to get the differences between the offset of the container and the image to get the actual position of the image regard its container and set this value to the `left` property of the image.

Here is the code that I have added:

```
var leftCenterDiv = $("#center").offset().left;
var leftImage = $("#image").offset().left;

$("#image").css("left", 0);
$("#image").css("left", leftImage - leftCenterDiv);
```

And the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om6gt7z0/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Give the image an absolute horizontal position to start from:

```
#image {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 45px;
}
```

Comment: But in my case I do not know where the image will be so I cannot set a initial left value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the image with initial position so that even adding the pixel it wont change i.e. `left`:45px`. but when you add pixel to existing one and to avoid moving position  can be done adding`!important` to the left

```
#image {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 45px !important;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om6gt7z0/2/)

Comment: But in your JS the image does not move.

Comment: @Error404 what is your expected result

Comment: To move the image from the current position, not to add some pixels to put it on the same position that is by default.

Comment: Finally I got a solution to get it.